# Работа с массивами C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как сформировать массив положительных из уже существующего массива ,как именно работать с размерностью нового массива,если по правилу его значение размерности должно быть фиксированным,но ведь при изменении изначального массива ,количество положительных чисел может изменяться.

Answer (score 3):

1. Можно использовать статический массив, в котором мы работаем с первыми элементами

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <vector>
   #define MAX 1000
   using namespace std;

   int main(){
   int array1[MAX];
   int array2[MAX];
   int size1 = 30;
   int size2 = 0;
   //Формируем первый массив и выводим на экран
   for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
       array1[i] = -50 + rand() % 100;
       cout << array1[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   //Формируем второй массив
   for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
       if (array1[i] > 0) {
           array2[size2] = array1[i];
           size2++;
       }
   }
   //выводим на экран второй массив
   for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
       cout << array2[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Или использовать контейнер vector

   ```
   vector<int> mas1;
   vector<int> mas2;
   for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
       mas1.push_back(-50 + rand() % 100);
       cout << mas1[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < mas1.size(); i++) {
       if (mas1[i] > 0) {
           mas2.push_back(mas1[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Лучше использовать `<random>`

Comment: @dlm0n это зачем интересно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52869166/13970074

Comment: @dlm0n вы же поняли, что задача не про генерацию массива?

Comment: Я говорю в целом про код в ответе. Если бы это был код ТС с минимальными исправлениями, то другое дело

Comment: @dlm0n в целом код в ответе прекрасен. В данной задаче характеристики псевдослучайного распределения не важны иначе это было бы указано в условии.

Comment: Ахаха :D Ну ладно, раз прекрасен, то не надо исправлять тогда

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я посоветую всё же разобраться в том, что такое динамическая область памяти и как там хранятся данные. Вы наверняка привыкли использовать простой массив с фиксированным количеством хранящих в себе объектов. Но есть "динамические массивы", которые хранятся в куче. Если Вы знаете, что такое указатели, тогда Вам будет не трудно в этом разобраться.

Вот пример динамического массива:

```
int* array; // указатель на тип данных int
array = new int [5]{1,5,3,6,2}; // выделение памяти под массив на 5 объектов {1,5,3,6,2}

// теперь указатель содержит адрес данного массива и с ним можно работать, как с простым массивом
std::cout << array[1] << std::endl; // output: 5
array[2] = 99;
std::cout << array[2] << std::endl; // output: 99

delete[] array; // но при окончании работы с массивом нужно очистить память

// после очистки памяти указатель array хранит адрес, но на пустой участок памяти  
// и мы можем продолжить работать

array = new int [2]{1,5}; // создадим массив на 2 объекта
// а что если мы хотим добавить еще один объект? - Пожалуйста
int *temp = new int[3];
for(int i < 2) 
{
   temp[i] = array[i];
}
temp[2] = 888;

delete[] array; // вновь очищаем память

array = temp; // говорим, что наш указатель будет знать про наш новый массив

// и дальше можно работать с массивом так же, как и ранее

std::cout << array[2] << std::endl; // output: 888
```